# Get data transferred from S3Object

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am hoping to access the Amazon S3 API to determine how much data has been transferred on a single S3 Object. Is this possible?

I have looked through the documentation yet can not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible via the API as such, however, you should be able to calculate this yourself by facilitating [Server Access Logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html):

> [...] An Amazon S3 bucket can be configured to create access log
>   records for the requests made against it. An access log record
>   contains details about the request such as the request type, the
>   resource with which the request worked, and the time and date that the
>   request was processed. [...]

This is can be configured via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as well, see [Managing Bucket Logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html) for details.

Any decent analytics package should be able to provide respective aggregates for the generated [Server Access Log Format](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html), ideally including the transferred data already - otherwise you would need to do the math yourself from the number of requests (still inconvenient, but likely automatable one way or another).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that will do nicely :)